# React JS Mapping certain indexes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapping, react-redux, react-props

I have a prop called **Friends** which looks like:

```
friends: Map(...)
    0: Array[2]
       0: "3"  // friendId
       1: Record(...)
          0: Array[2]
             0: "firstName"
             1: "Bob"
          1: Array[2]
             0: "lastName"
             1: "Smith"
    ...
```

How can I only map certain indexes from it? The following maps the entire list and prints out firstName and lastName.

```
friends.mapEntries(([friendId, frn]) => [
    friendId,
        <option value={friendId} key={friendId}>
            {frn.firstName} {frn.lastName}
        </option>,
]).toList()
```

However I only want to map entries on specific values. I have another prop called **Event** which contains a List called **friendsInEvent** which just contains the ID of the friends.

```
event: Record(...)
...
6: Array[2]
   0: "friendsInEvent"
   1: List(...)
      0: "3"
```

Again I can print this out using:

```
{friendsInEvent.map(([friendId, frn]) => [
     <div key={friendId}>
         {friendId}
     </div>,
])}
```

How can I merge the two together and map firstName and lastName of friendsInEvent? Or is it easier to just store firstName and lastName again?

Comment: What data structure is 'List'? Is that an array?

Comment: it looks like this is from immutablejs library. I am not sure but maybe merge could help

Comment: Why not use .filter before map? If it is a large list you even could reduce friendsInEvent to a dictionary, and your predicate in a filter will look like `!!friendsInEventDict[friendId]`

Comment: @Yozi, how would this work?

Comment: @H1ggsy, If I understand you properly, you want filter `friends` by values in `friendsInEvent` before iterate over it. Something like [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7].filter(x => x %2).map(x=>console.log(x)) // print 1, 3, 5, 7.  Am I right?

Comment: @H1ggsy, the `filter` function works like `if` condition, everything that is not true will not be used for next map. So only thing you need is to write right predicate for filter

Comment: @Yozi, ok thank you, I did something like this and it worked.